# Getting the result from plain text then create summary in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to ask a question on how to make a list in android studio? what I want to do is to get the input in the plain text and list it somewhere (can be stacked) and then if I click certain button, the summary of all input will be placed and the price will be added altogether in the  end. I am new to android studio and I really wanna learn. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hi, I think you can try to create a Todo app (there are lots of tutorials for this on the internet) and then adapt it to your problem.

Comment: Well then, by all means, ask such a question.